# Getting component propTypes as string

Tags: reactjs

I will like to make a wrapper component that will **automatically display its children's proptypes as a string**.

## Example

For example, my component may be:

```
export class abc extends Component {
    static propTypes = {
        disabled: PropTypes.bool,
        text: PropTypes.oneOf(['a','b'])
    }
}
```

The wrapper will take in the component:

```
<Wrapper>
    <abc />
</Wrapper>
```

And output HTML that looks like:

```
<pre>
    disabled: PropTypes.bool
    text: PropTypes.oneOf(['a', 'b'])
</pre>
```

## What I have tried

I have tried extracting props directly from the actual children, and ended up with a wrapper component that looks like this:

```
const wrapper = props => (<pre>
  {Object.entries(props.children.type.propTypes).map((entry) => (
    <div key={entry[0]}>{entry[0]}: {getPropTypeFromFunction(entry[1])}<br/></div>
  ))}
</pre>)
```

where the `getPropTypeFromFunction` method is:

```
const getPropTypeFromFunction = func => {
  for (const k in PropTypes) {
    switch (func) {
      case PropTypes[k]:
        return k
      case PropTypes[k].isRequired:
        return `${k}.isRequired`
      default:
        break;
    }
  }
  return "Unknown PropType"
}
```

This however does not work when we get non-primitive (?) proptypes (eg `PropTypes.onOf(['a', 'b'])`. Also it feels kind of hacky to have to deal with something seemingly so simple this way.

Is there some kind of elegant solution to this (ideally without any external libraries?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using [react-docgen](https://github.com/reactjs/react-docgen), which uses [recast](https://github.com/benjamn/recast) internally. This works by parsing the entire source file as a string into an [Abstract Syntax Tree (AST)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) which is then used to generate the doc. There are some libraries using this to implement documentation, such as [storybook.js](https://storybook.js.org/) and their [info add-on](https://github.com/storybooks/storybook/blob/master/addons/info/README.md), which I ended up using.